# Clojure test with multiple assertions

Tags: clojure, tdd

I am starting to learn how to write tests for my Clojure program.
I have a test with multiple assertions (calls to `is`).
I want the test to stop running as soon as the first assertion fails.
Here is my test:

```
(deftest register-one-command
  (testing "Register-one-command"
    (do
      (is (= 0 (count @test/list-of-commands)))
      (test/add-to-list-of-commands ["A"])
      (is (= 1 (count @test/list-of-commands))))))
```

If the first `is` fails, I want the whole thing to fail.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I notice the reformatting of the code so the close brackets are on the same line rather than below the matching opening bracket. I am new to Clojure so am probably doing it wrong but I like the close brackets below the opening ones because it makes it a lot easier for me to copy and paste individual lines. Also when I edit the code it is important to match opening and closing brackets and not every editor is going to highlight for me.

Comment: Check out this post https://adambard.com/blog/acceptable-error-handling-in-clojure/
While it's not about testing it talks about how to do a general if success then ... if success ...  -> which is basically an error monad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to just wrap the different tests in an `and`

```
(deftest register-one-command
  (testing "Register-one-command"
    (is (and
          (= 0 (count @test/list-of-commands))
          (test/add-to-list-of-commands ["A"])
          (= 1 (count @test/list-of-commands))))))
```

If possible, however, I would try to restructure the tests so that this extra bit of complexity is unnecessary.